# How do I hardcode in the post date into my WordPress post?

Tags: wordpress, date, shortcode, hardcode

I am in the middle of customizing my Canvas theme by WooThemes and would like to hardcode in the date into my posts so that it looks something like this:

**July 7, 2011** Paragraph text goes here text.....Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tincidunt congue mauris, nec porttitor felis blandit ac. Curabitur vestibulum, arcu nec suscipit laoreet, sapien quam egestas ligula.

Not sure what function I call to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[the_date](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_date) should be able to help you.

Comment: would I hardcode this date into my theme post file or generic WordPress post file? Not sure where I place this so that I can get the date to show up on post excerpts as well..

Comment: It would be in your theme's post file. Your theme's [excerpt](http://codex.wordpress.org/Excerpt) code should be somewhere, the_date will need to be put in there too I think if you want it to show up there as well.

Comment: for some reason every time I try to use the_date() it displays the post date a line above the excerpt text.  I would like the post date to display on the same line as the excerpt text..I can't figure this out for the life of me.